# sed (replacing / with \/ using shell)

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using a shell script that uses sed

I have this sentence in a variable

```
kpi="ENFRIADORA CONDENSADA POR AIRE/AIRE-AIRE/AGUA - MENSUAL"
```

if in a console I put

```
echo $kpi | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

I see

```
ENFRIADORA CONDENSADA POR AIRE\/AIRE-AIRE\/AGUA - MENSUAL
```

That is what I want, but when I put this in a script like this

```
echo start
echo $kpi2
kpi_2=`echo $kpi2 | sed 's/\//\\\//g'`
echo $kpi_2
echo end
```

That I see is :

```
start
ENFRIADORA CONDENSADA POR AIRE/AIRE-AIRE/AGUA - MENSUAL
sed: -e expresion #1, character 9: unknown option to `s'

end
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$> kpi_2=$( echo $kpi | sed 's/\//\\\//g' )

$> echo $kpi_2
ENFRIADORA CONDENSADA POR AIRE\/AIRE-AIRE\/AGUA - MENSUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
kpi_2=`echo $kpi2 | sed 's:\/:\\\/:g'`
```